# ffmpeg very bad quality mp4 conversion

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4

Trying to convert mp4 with ffmpeg, two passes, with -crf 50 and seems like it doen't impact on video quality. It's always very poor.

```
'/usr/bin/ffmpeg' '-y' '-i' '/app/storage/7/02/f47a2133-d0fe-6e7f-5e76-3efd22a88027_original.mp4' '-threads' '12' '-vcodec' 'libx264' '-acodec' 'libfaac' '-b:v' '1000k' '-refs' '6' '-coder' '1' '-sc_threshold' '40' '-flags' '+loop' '-me_range' '16' '-subq' '7' '-i_qfactor' '0.71' '-qcomp' '0.6' '-qdiff' '4' '-trellis' '1' '-b:a' '128k' '-pix_fmt' 'yuv420p' '-crf' '50' '-profile' 'baseline' '-movflags' '+faststart' '-vf' '[in]scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2[out]' '-pass' '1' '-passlogfile' '/tmp/ffmpeg-passes5cde7ed5d2937fzaaz/pass-5cde7ed5d2caf' '/app/storage/7/02/f47a2133-d0fe-6e7f-5e76-3efd22a88027_temp.mp4'
```

```
'/usr/bin/ffmpeg' '-y' '-i' '/app/storage/7/02/f47a2133-d0fe-6e7f-5e76-3efd22a88027_original.mp4' '-threads' '12' '-vcodec' 'libx264' '-acodec' 'libfaac' '-b:v' '1000k' '-refs' '6' '-coder' '1' '-sc_threshold' '40' '-flags' '+loop' '-me_range' '16' '-subq' '7' '-i_qfactor' '0.71' '-qcomp' '0.6' '-qdiff' '4' '-trellis' '1' '-b:a' '128k' '-pix_fmt' 'yuv420p' '-crf' '50' '-profile' 'baseline' '-movflags' '+faststart' '-vf' '[in]scale=trunc(iw/2)*2:trunc(ih/2)*2[out]' '-pass' '2' '-passlogfile' '/tmp/ffmpeg-passes5cde7ed5d2937fzaaz/pass-5cde7ed5d2caf' '/app/storage/7/02/f47a2133-d0fe-6e7f-5e76-3efd22a88027_temp.mp4'
```

Original: https://giant.gfycat.com/CreepyZigzagFish.mp4
Converted: https://leonardo.osnova.io/f47a2133-d0fe-6e7f-5e76-3efd22a88027/-/format/mp4/

How to fix video quality? I've tried to change crf value, but seems like it doesn't matter.

Comment: CRF doesn't apply to 2-pass encoding. Also, the source is already x264-encoded. Don't expect to compress it much more without lowering resolution.

Comment: I would expect very bad quality at CRF 50. Try 20. Also  CRF + a bitrate (and 2 pass) does not make sense.

Comment: Why are you re-encoding in the first place? `-b:v` and `-crf` are mutually exclusive: only use one. That's possibly why it didn't make a difference when you changed `-crf`. If you're using libfaac then that means your ffmpeg is ancient and you should update. And don't use a billion options like it is the year 2008: just use `-preset` and you can eliminate everything from and including `-refs` to `-trellis`. See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).